# I have a Lenovo Flex 5 with a 620 graphics, and I cannont turn down the brightness.

Tags: windows, graphics-card, brightness

It's been like that since I got it. I found an answer on here and tried to use it, but it did not work on mine. Although, when I went to Device manager, then to the graphics, a message appeared that said it was disabled because it had problems. Is there anything I can do to fix it myself? It's still pretty new, so there shouldn't be any big issues.

Comment: Welcome on Superuser. What answer are you referring to? and which steps provided did you try? You can get the link to the answer via the little 'share' button under it, simply [post](https://superuser.com/posts/1364484/edit) it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

We can troubleshoot the issue as below:

1. Can we enable the graphics on Device manager? If so, then we can view if we can turn down the brightness?
2. After we enable the graphics, if we still can not turn down the brightness, I suggest we download the latest graphics card driver on Lenovo's official website, then install it. View if we can turn down the brightness.